# DefinitelyTyped log4javascript missing module declaration

Tags: typescript, definitelytyped, log4javascript

I'm having a hard time using the following typings file in my project:

https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/log4javascript

Apperantly, the file is missing a module declaration, causing typescript to complain that it can't find the module 'log4javascript' when I put the following statement in my typescript file:

`import * as log4javascript from 'log4javascript';`

When I manually edit the index.d.ts file that is installed by running the command

`typings install dt~log4javascript --global --save`

and I add this module declaration:

`declare module "log4javascript" {
    import test = log4javascript;
    export = test;
}`

at the end of the file, then the compiler no longer complains and my code even works without using the `import *` statement.

**So how am I supposed to use the typings file so that I can use log4javascript with typescript?**

**UPDATE**

I've managed to work around it by creating a `custom.d.ts` file which declares the log4javascript module alongside the generated root index.d.ts of typings and added a `///<reference path="..." />` statement in my main.ts file used by requirejs.
I still don't feel that this is the correct way to do it, but it works for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to work around it by creating a `custom.d.ts` file which declares the log4javascript module alongside the generated root index.d.ts of typings and added a `///<reference path="..." />` statement in my main.ts file used by requirejs.
I still don't feel that this is the correct way to do it, but it works for now.